# Pending Intetn and set alarm repeating

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

How do i can run a piece of code let's say every 1 seconde??

Here is my snip of codes:
MainActivity:

```
 private Context ctx;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            ctx = this;
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      AlarmManager am  = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                      int inter =  1000;
                      Intent i = new Intent(ctx, Brodcast.class);
                      PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, i, 0);
                      am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), inter, pi);
                }

            });
        }
```

Brodcast Class:

```
public class Brodcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(arg0, "This wil appear every one seconde", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("this will apear every one seconde" , "this will apear every one seconde");
    }

}
```

But neither log or Toast are shown why??? please help.

Comment: do you have your broadcast defined the in the AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: yes you either need to have intent-filter set for broadcast or register it in code using Context.registerReceiver()

Comment: Oh i forgot thank you if you want write as an answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you have defined your broadcast receiver in the manifest file or you register it using the code as suggested in the comments.